# How to design XML based and testable repository?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, file-io

I'm writing XML based repository. For now it's a single class with basic [CRUD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) operations. One of the parameters passed in constructor is `url` of the file where repository will be kept.

```
public Repository(string fileUrl, IRepositorySchema schema)
```

Now I'd like to write unit tests for this class. I don't want to use real files. I've done some research and found [SystemWrapper](http://systemwrapper.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Wrapper%20classes&referringTitle=Home) library which might help me with that task.

Real question is, how can I change my repository class so I could mock/stub file? Should I inject file system along with file url?

Comment: Seems like the right approach. Do you have specific doubts about it?

Comment: `File` class is static, so how can I inject it? I've heared there are ways for doing it.

Comment: When you use a wrapper you don't call static methods of the BCL. The entire point of a wrapper is to not call them. Call through an interface. Inject an implementation of that interface and use that object.

Comment: Wow, I didn't hit on that. I'm going try with this.

Comment: Should I use IFileWrap or is there any other more suitable interface for that purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely a good direction to mock the files for testing.

Using [SystemWrapper](http://systemwrapper.codeplex.com/), you won't call [`System.IO.File`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.aspx) static methods anymore, but instead you pass in the file instance into the repository as [`SystemInterface.IO.IFile`](http://systemwrapper.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#SystemWrapper4/SystemInterface/IO/IFile.cs) and perform all the calls through it, the same as you do with repository schema:

```
public Repository(SystemInterface.IO.IFile file, IRepositorySchema schema)
```

For production you will then use the [`SystemWrapper.IO.FileWrap`](http://systemwrapper.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#SystemWrapper4/SystemWrapper/IO/FileWrap.cs) instace provided by SystemWrapper, which is implemented using `System.IO.File`, and for testing you will provide your own `SystemInterface.IO.IFile` implementation that suits your testing needs.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend taking a look at [System.IO.Abstractions](https://github.com/tathamoddie/System.IO.Abstractions). Looks like it's under more active development.

You can follow the same approach with it. Just constructor inject `IFileSystem`. In your unit tests you can then mock that with a library of your choice or use the handy [testing helpers](https://github.com/tathamoddie/System.IO.Abstractions/tree/master/TestingHelpers) that come along with the library.